# How to store data with JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I don't know JavaScript and Jquery very well.

I want to save specific data from HTML tables in webpage (I use a form) into my database (MySQL) with Ajax request and PHP.

I don't want to save every user event (edit a cell (`<td></td>`) in table, delete a row (`<tr></tr>`) or change order with drag and drop Jquery plugin).

I want to save ALL changes in my form.

So I have to store information about every event (new data) with JavaScript and Jquery.
How is the best way to do so?

I can temporary store data in webpage or in array. Maybe exist another method to do so.

Then with `$("form").submit(function(){})` and `$.ajax()` in it with PHP file I can update data in database.

I am using MySQL, PHP, Javascript, jQuery, jQuery UI and other plugins.

Comment: Where's your code now?

Comment: If you really really need all events you'll end up with something that is similar to what I show you here, so you might already start doing it right from start: [EDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what do you want. Maybe you can use the localStorage to save some clients preferences.

Comment: You could use the [jQuery DataTables Plugin](http://www.datatables.net/examples/index) (examples).... This plugin lets you add rows, delete rows, and even post the table via php or ajax post method... You'll have to buy this plugin according to their pricing plans, but if you're looking for free alternatives, then maybe you could search for something similar... [:::link:::](http://www.datatables.net/)

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of the `.on()` [function from JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/), use It to bind events on all your changes, you can then instantiate a global array of events in javascript like so

```
var myEventHappeningListForThisPage = [];
```

then you could push objects into it like so

```
myEventHappeningListForThisPage.push({ id: 123, eventname: "HELLO", something: undefined });
```

finally you could then post the object to the server and save or store what you have to there.

For the `on` binding, like at this example

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
    myEventHappeningListForThisPage.push({ id: 123, eventname: "HELLO", something: undefined }); //This is the line I added to do your "Local save"
});
```